# Unassigned variable and "Not all code paths return a value" workaround?

Tags: c#, performance, methods, return-value

```cs
private static char GetGuess()
{ 
    char guess;
    bool guessInputSuccess = false;

    while (!guessInputSuccess)
    { 
        Console.Write("Guess your letter: ");

        char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out guess); 

        if (!char.IsLetter(guess))
        { 
            Console.Write("You have not entered a letter from a-z."); 
        }
        else
        { 
            guessInputSuccess = true; 
        } 
    }

    return guess; 
}
```

As it currently looks, I cannot return `guess` because it's unassigned. The way I'd usually get around this is by assigning `guess` to a random character. Since the `while` loop will continue until a valid character from a-z is input, one could be confident that by the time it returns, a character from a-z will be assigned to `guess`. I personally don't like this workaround because for me, it feels sloppy.

My question is: Is there any way I can keep guess initialized but unassigned in the beginning of the method and still have it set and returned properly by the end of the methods execution?

Comment: `char` is a value type, so it has to contain a value. If you don't want to make it `char?`, then you can mitigate the sloppiness of the random value with `char guess = default(char)`.

Comment: [`char.IsLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?view=netframework-4.8) will return `true` for things that are not a letter between a-z, like the Greek letter gamma, γ. If you want to limit it to just a-z, you'll need to test `guess >= 'a' && guess <= 'z'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just return as soon as you enter a correct guess - and loop forever until then. You don't need `guessInputSuccess` at all, and `guess` can have a smaller scope:

```cs
private static char GetGuess()
{ 
    while (true)
    { 
        Console.Write("Guess your letter: ");
        if (char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out char guess) && 
            char.IsLetter(guess))
        {
            return guess;
        }
        Console.Write("You have not entered a letter from a-z."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wicked efficiency!

Comment: For slightly more efficiency, there's no need to perform `if (char.IsLetter(guess))` if `char.TryParse()` returns false.

Comment: @foamu - I get that; I'm just saying `char.TryParse()` returns useful information, so you can instead do `if (char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out char guess) && char.IsLetter(guess)) { return guess; }`, which will skip testing whether what is entered is a letter if it doesn't even parse to a char.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it correct. You can assign an `empty` char code which is `'\0'`.

I.e `guess='\0'`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `do...while` loop, the compiler can see that `guess` is always assigned:

```
char guess;
bool guessInputSuccess = false;

do 
{ 
    Console.Write("Guess your letter: ");

    char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out guess); 

    if (!char.IsLetter(guess))
    { 
        Console.Write("You have not entered a letter from a-z."); 
    }
    else
    { 
        guessInputSuccess = true; 
    } 
} while (!guessInputSuccess);

return guess;
```

Alternatively, give `guess` an initial value. *You* know that it's always going to be assigned, so it doesn't really matter what the value is:

```
char guess = '\0';
bool guessInputSuccess = false;

while (!guessInputSuccess)
{ 
    Console.Write("Guess your letter: ");

    char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out guess); 

    if (!char.IsLetter(guess))
    { 
        Console.Write("You have not entered a letter from a-z."); 
    }
    else
    { 
        guessInputSuccess = true; 
    } 
}

return guess;
```